# Building multiple sites from one .net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have created a website in .Net, this site does some functionality (where it makes some simple bookings) that is handled mainly within the Code Behind of each page and master pages. The source code then does all the calls to server where needed.

Some clients are wishing to use this site, and all require some changes, all are cosmetic and things I would do myself. Some sites have additional panels etc which could mean some sites have extra code in their pages code behind too, which would cause difference between sites.

What I want to do is 're-brand' multiple sites from this one site, all with an individual style. However I want them all to be in one 'solution' or share code behind as this means they can all share any code fixes I may make.

What options do I have to achieve this? What obstacles have others faced in a similar situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope you realize, that you are, fundamentally building Visual studios the web version.. Its a lot of work to make an IDE with functionality that the everyday business person can use, best way to get this done is try to build an app that can do all the work of an ide, without having to hard code.

Comment: Oh and if you dont want it to do all the hard work with big and major arithmetic, go take a look at some html5, just a brainwave here, but if you can drag and drop dives, get their location and save that in the css, you could be on to something.

Comment: Looks to me you need separation of core business logic (like making reservation, querying for availability), from presentation. Hence,  I suggest taking an api approach to perform your business needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding it correctly, you would like to create a CMS system.

If that's the case, you have a couple of things that you can do:

- Create an own layout/templating framework that sets css and placeholders dynamiccly.
- You can create another project and put the output folder to the bin folder of your CMS (that way, you share functionality).

Kr